# I would like to put a list in an object variable

Tags: python

Something like :

```
departement = {
  'departement :': [str(x) for x in depart_noms],
  'formation': [str(x) for x in formations]
}
```

I want to do this to generate a json file except my data is in arrays

I want to build a struct like:

```
[{"departement": "Économique",
     "formations": [
           {"nom": "Bachelier en informatique de gestion",
            "modules": [ { "accr": "INAF0001-2",
             "lien": "/cocoon/cours/INAF0001-2.html" },
            { "accr": "INAB0002-1",
              "lien": "/cocoon/cours/INAB0002-1.html" },
             ]}
}]
```

Is that possible to make in a single object variable for all data ?

Comment: The curly braces make the values sets. Is that what you wanted? If you just want a list then remove the curly braces and you will be left with a list of strings.

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  Can you give us examples of what `depart_noms` and `formations` look like, and just what you want for output?

Comment: can you provide a sample of your current data? I'm a little confused on what you are asking.

Comment: if I do :
 print([{str(x) for x in depart_noms}]) 
 I have : 
[{'Pédagogique', 'Technique', 'Social', 'Économique', 'Paramédical'}]
I want to put it inside departement directly

Comment: Ah...I missed what @mhawke is pointing out.  You are going to end up with the values in your `department` map being lists each containing a single set.  That isn't going to be something you can turn into JSON.  Is that your problem?

Comment: Please add the values of your variables and your expected output to your question. This is more useful than requiring us to dig your requirements out of the comments.

Comment: Lukes like that you should learn list comprehension properly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of your code with some simple lists as additional input:

```
depart_noms = ['a', 'b', 'c']
formations = ['x', 'y', 'z']
departement = {
  'departement :': [{str(x) for x in depart_noms}],
  'formation': [{str(x) for x in formations}]
}
```

This is perfectly valid Python, but this leads to a structure that can't be JSON serialized because it contains sets (due to the curly braces), which can't be represented in JSON.  If you try to execute `json.dumps(departement)`, you'll get the error:

```
TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable
```

If instead, your code is this:

```
import json

depart_noms = ['a', 'b', 'c']
formations = ['x', 'y', 'z']
departement = {
  'departement :': [str(x) for x in depart_noms],
  'formation': [str(x) for x in formations]
}

print(json.dumps(departement))
```

Your resuilt will be this:

```
{"departement :": ["a", "b", "c"], "formation": ["x", "y", "z"]}
```

I'm just taking a stab at this somehow answering your question.  If not, then please provide more information to better define what your problem is.